# Error when using WordPress walker (Walker_Nav_Menu), class inserting Anchor parent in submenu

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

This class creates a menu with different sub-levels :

```
class Bootstrap_Collapse_NavWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
    $output .= "<ul>";
}

public function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = []){
    $output .= "</ul>";
}

public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [], $id = 0){

    $itemClasses = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names_li = "";
    $class_names_a = "";
    $class_names_i = "";
    $item_output = "";
    $hasChildrenElm = $args->walker->has_children;
    if ( $hasChildrenElm ) {
        $class_names_li = 'dropdown';
    }

    if ( $depth === 0 && !$hasChildrenElm ) {
        $class_names_a = 'nav-link scrollto';
    }

    $activeElement = "";
    if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $itemClasses ) ) $activeElement .'active';

    $elementUrl = ! empty( $item->url ) ? esc_url($item->url) : '';
    $output .= '<li class="'.$class_names_li.'">';
    if ( $hasChildrenElm ) {
        $output .= '<a class="'.$class_names_a.$activeElement.'" href="'.$elementUrl.'">
                        <span>'.$item->title.'</span>';
        $class_names_i .= ($depth !== 0) ? "bi bi-chevron-right" : "bi bi-chevron-down";
        $output .= '<i class="'.$class_names_i.'"></i>';
    }elseif($item->title !== ""){
        $output .= '<a class="'.$class_names_a.$activeElement.'" href="'.$elementUrl.'-1">'.$item->title.'</a>';
    }
}
public function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = []){
    $output .= "</li>";
}
}
```

I am waiting for the following HTML :

```
<ul>
<li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#menu1">menu 1</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#menu2">menu 2</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#"><span>Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><span>Deep Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

But It print this HTML :

```
<ul>
<li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#menu1">menu 1</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#menu2">menu 2</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#dropdownLink"><span>Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <ul>
        <a class="" href="#dropdownLink"></a>
        <li>
            <a class="" href="#dropdownLink"></a>
            <a href="#">Drop Down 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><span>Deep Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <a class="" href="#dropdownLink"></a>
                <li>
                    <a class="" href="#dropdownLink"></a>
                    <a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see at each menu level the script prints again the anchor tag of the parent menu, I am not being able to identify when the script loop inserts the parent TAG anchor, you can help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, missing close anchor tag correct code:

```
class Bootstrap_Collapse_NavWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
    $output .= "<ul>";
}

public function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = [])
{
    $output .= "</ul>";
}

public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [], $id = 0){

    $itemClasses = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names_li = "";
    $class_names_a = "";
    $class_names_i = "";
    $item_output = "";
    $hasChildrenElm = $args->walker->has_children;
    if ( $hasChildrenElm ) {
        $class_names_li = 'dropdown';
    }

    if ( $depth === 0 && !$hasChildrenElm ) {
        $class_names_a = 'nav-link scrollto';
    }

    $activeElement = "";
    if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $itemClasses ) ) $activeElement .'active';

    $elementUrl = ! empty( $item->url ) ? esc_url($item->url) : '';
    if(!empty($elementUrl)){
        $output .= '<li class="'.$class_names_li.'">';
        if ( $hasChildrenElm ) {
            $output .= '<a class="'.$class_names_a.$activeElement.'" href="'.$elementUrl.'">
                            <span>'.$item->title.'</span>';
            $class_names_i .= ($depth !== 0) ? "bi bi-chevron-right" : "bi bi-chevron-down";
            $output .= '<i class="'.$class_names_i.'"></i></a>';
        }else{ 
            $output .= '<a class="'.$class_names_a.$activeElement.'11" href="'.$elementUrl.'">'.$item->title.'</a>';
        }
    }
}
public function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [])
{

    $output .= "</li>";
}
}
```